# How do I prevent having to fill in parameter names in flask-restful?

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am making an extremely simple API using flask-restful and want to process POST-parameters without having to require the users to enter a parameter name, e.g.

```
curl -d "data" localhost
```

instead of

```
curl -d "name=data" localhost
```

The API is used internally so this usage is not problematic, however, I can't get it to work. If I do

```
parser.add_argument('', type=str)
```

then I'm still required to use the equality sign, e.g. `-d "=data"`.

```
parser.add_argumnent(None, type=str)
```

raises an exception.
Without `parser.add_argument()` `parser.parse_args()` returns an empty container.

Comment: study http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.args, and make your parsing based in the dict.

Comment: I dont know how new you are but you can access the request object with `from flask import request` and the used it as `if 'data' in request.args` do something

Comment: I had to use request.form instead of request.args, but all the same, it works now. Thank you! :)

Comment: @svd: Do not hesitate to provide the solution you found by writing an answer to your own question. This could be useful to other people ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @brunsgaard:

[Request.form](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.form) captures all the POST (and PUT) data in a dictionary.

If the input is formed exactly as in the question, the following code grabs it from the dictionary:

```
request.form.keys()[0]
```